# Batch processing in ENVI?

Tags: batch, envi

I opened a headerless flat binary file in ENVI.

I used menu->save file as->TIFF/GeoTIFF to save it as tiff image.

I have 100s of images to convert into tiff.

How can I do this batch processing in ENVI?

In other words, for batch processing in ENVI is there a GUI or command line?

Comment: For batch processing in ENVI, I think that you need IDL. What about using gdal_translate for this ?

Comment: sure, see www.gdal.org , then gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88058 for an example of batch with gdal

Answer (score 1):

IDL is a prior choice if you are familiar with it. These two lines code can solve it:

```
data=read_bianry(filename,data_dims=[100,200])
write_tiff,out_filename,data,/float
```